# Clipboard.js loop buttons

Tags: javascript, twig, clipboard.js

I use clipboard.js and after a click on one of my buttons I want to show a success message under the button, but I am not able to loop throught.

This is the button:

```
<button type="button" class="clipboard-button button-rect" data-clipboard-text="{{ site.author.email|safe_email }}">
  <span class="button-text">Get in touch</span>
  <span class="clipboard-message">My E-Mail has been copied</span>
</button>
```

And this the js:

```
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.clipboard-button');

clipboard.on('success', function () {
    var message = document.querySelectorAll('.clipboard-message');
    message.style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(function () {
        message.style.opacity = '0';
    }, 2000);
});
```

I want to show the message under the button which was pressed and not for every button.

I would appreciate your help, I tried so much. I'm an JS beginner btw, so be patient please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On thing you should look at is achieving to retrieve the clicked DOM element (a button in this case). It will then be easy to find the corresponding `.clipboard-message` span element.

To retrieve the clicked element you can use the parameter given to the `success` event callback function, like stated here: https://clipboardjs.com/#events

Then your JavaScript code becomes:

```
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.clipboard-button');

clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
    // e.trigger corresponds to the clipboard-button DOM element that triggered the event
    // You can then use querySelector(...) to retrieve to first child element with the class clipboard-message
    var message = e.trigger.querySelector('.clipboard-message');
    message.style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(function () {
        message.style.opacity = '0';
    }, 2000);
});
```

Here is a working code snippet for you to try:

```js
var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.clipboard-button');

clipboard.on('success', function (e) {
    var message = e.trigger.querySelector('.clipboard-message');
    message.style.opacity = '1';
    setTimeout(function () {
        message.style.opacity = '0';
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.clipboard-message {
    color: green;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clipboard@2/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="clipboard-button button-rect" data-clipboard-text="{{ site.author.email|safe_email }}">
  <span class="button-text">Get in touch</span>
  <span class="clipboard-message">My E-Mail has been copied</span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="clipboard-button button-rect" data-clipboard-text="{{ site.author.email|safe_email }}">
  <span class="button-text">Here is your ID</span>
  <span class="clipboard-message">My ID has been copied</span>
</button>
```